# Выдаёт ошибку при построении проекта на Андроид 4.4.2

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь установить на планшет под Андроид 4.4.2 приложение, но получаю в лог:

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0] C:\Users\Anton\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\d7b94c50a18dd1a58dc1b8b2998d0dc4\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 9
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 9,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 14,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared 
in library [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0]
```

Попробуйте прочитать текст стактрейса. В нём говорится о том, что используемая вами библиотека требует, чтобы минимальная версия API проекта была `>= 14`, а в вашем проекте установлена версия API = `9`. Либо повысьте минимальную версию API проекта, либо уберите библиотеку из зависимостей.